# I want to display one of 10 videos at the top of a page by clicking an "image still" further down the same page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display one of 10 videos at the top of an html page by clicking an "image still" further down the same page. Ideally want to use HTML5 and CSS but will use jquery if necessary.

Comment: Show some effort if you want help and by that I mean where is the code showing what you've done?

Comment: I'm looking for guidance on how to approach this problem beofre starting the code. I know nothing of jquery but am quite good with HTML anf CSS.

Comment: Well then give us some HTML and CSS to work with and then we can help you do the JS parts if need be.

Comment: ok here is the page with the video player and the video choices - http://www.ablcomponents.co.uk/videos/video-gallery.html. There is some element CSS but the most of it is in the style sheet (it is quite big at the mo) - http://www.ablcomponents.co.uk/CSS/abl-components.css.

Comment: OK so at this point you want them to be able to click on any of the video thumbnails at the bottom, take them back up to the top of the page, and start playing the video they chose?

Comment: Yes that is correct. So whatever video they choose will play in the defined area at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is simple, but let's say you included a YouTube video on your site like so...

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/W7qWa52k-nE" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

...and then you had a bunch of image thumbnails that also contained the location of the video in their data attribute...

```
<img src="image1.jpg" data-video="jsd07sd">
<img src="image2.jpg" data-video="sjsfjs0">
<img src="image3.jpg" data-video="ajhash9">
```

...then what's left is to listen for a click on these images, and change the location of the YouTube video because the browser will automatically refresh the video for you to the new location...

```
$('img').on('click', function(){

   var newVideo = $(this).attr('data-video');

   $('iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + newVideo);

});
```

That's the general concept behind what needs to happen.

Comment: I don't suppose I'm the first to need this siolution but looks like it will work for me. Thankyou so much for taking the time to sort it out.